# Radarchart in R - axes labels

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels, radar-chart

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/beautiful-radar-chart-in-r-using-fmsb-and-ggplot-packages/) to create a radar chart in R. I take the last chart in the tutorial (before ggplot is introduced), where the "average" profile is compared across cases. I set up my data in the way that is suggested by the tutorial, with the exception that I wanted to have the same max and min values across the "facets", so I fixed that to an overall min and an overall max.

The data is:

```
plot_dat_sameaxis <- structure(list(pol_demo = c(30, 0, 8.97007879362473, 11.0085519474347, 
                            8.53571259274138, 11.2005365744873, 8.71195021047779, 9.7436080644818, 
                            10.399697356034, 7.20225368831287, 7.19846449682537), pol_demo_online = c(30, 
                                                                                                      0, 9.98019651039727, 11.2121387931753, 10.3544128960645, 12.9789806839878, 
                                                                                                      10.9067032818662, 10.0244169530494, 10.0412566166562, 9.15927081711705, 
                                                                                                      7.82259925448071), pol_post_online = c(30, 0, 20.4990544471384, 
                                                                                                                                             22.7970962322516, 20.1055172731424, 24.8459684814346, 20.1141933651088, 
                                                                                                                                             15.3678777437076, 21.1504832571486, 23.2280265873052, 21.5491092364356
                                                                                                      ), pol_petition = c(30, 0, 22.4291973933483, 19.4974718426517, 
                                                                                                                          19.2697196682787, 24.3023818310391, 19.5669419418758, 22.3942976741465, 
                                                                                                                          18.8415089525096, 25.983262468582, 28.842684781718), pol_cntct_polit = c(30, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   0, 10.7532765882399, 10.815449497248, 12.7134692760538, 7.23126866059413, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   11.2047622893094, 11.4708587897729, 9.33114630516778, 9.60620574567012, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   10.6909820573769), pol_party = c(30, 0, 8.74403983440336, 7.77898781617009, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    9.02365487435948, 7.5573005918663, 9.55902871932231, 10.3628637158336, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    9.8557831406188, 7.67193215789611, 7.08669448709292), pol_other = c(30, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0, 11.949458207316, 9.43079720266811, 12.5014350323826, 9.03630081302701, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        12.9221923230867, 11.5716131017492, 12.1911878955728, 14.0101290367095, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        11.8331630213764), pol_demo_illegal = c(30, 0, 6.67469822553204, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                7.45950666840047, 7.49607838697717, 2.84726236356375, 7.01422786895309, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                9.0644639572591, 8.18893647629205, 3.13891949840709, 4.97630266469401
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        )), row.names = c("Max", "Min", "Average", "Only corona freedom", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Only corona economic", "Corona both", "Corona and other", "Only climate prot.", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Only racism", "Both racism and climate", "Other"), class = "data.frame")
```

I combine the axes customization from the tutorial with the last plot code. So I first take the function `create_beautiful_radarchart` from the website:

```
create_beautiful_radarchart <- function(data, color = "#00AFBB", 
                                        vlabels = colnames(data), vlcex = 0.7,
                                        caxislabels = NULL, title = NULL, ...){
  radarchart(
    data, axistype = 1,
    # Customize the grid
    cglcol = "grey", cglty = 1, cglwd = 0.8,
    # Customize the axis
    axislabcol = "grey", 
    # Variable labels
    vlcex = vlcex, vlabels = vlabels,
    caxislabels = caxislabels, title = title, ...
  )
}
```

Then the code to create the figure is:

```
opar <- par() 
# Define settings for plotting in a 3x4 grid, with appropriate margins:
par(mar = rep(0.8,4))
par(mfrow = c(3,3))
# Produce a radar-chart for each student
for (i in 4:nrow(plot_dat_sameaxis)) {
  create_beautiful_radarchart(
    plot_dat[c(1:3, i), ],
    pfcol = c("#99999980",NA),
    pcol= c(NA,2), plty = 1, plwd = 1,
    title = row.names(plot_dat_sameaxis)[i],
    caxislabels = c(0, 7.5, 15, 22.5, 30)
  )
}
```

I set the values in `caxislabels` to four equal segments by setting the `caxislabels` vector values. Firstly I wanted to have six to avoid the decimals, but I got an error. If someone can help with that, that's also appreciated.

However, the bigger issue is that after I run this code, the values that I get on the chart, don't reflect the `average` values from the dataset (the middle, shaded area). For example based on the chart, the average for `pol_party` should be roughly 15, but it's actually 8.74 in the dataset. I don't understand where the difference comes from, but the axis labels are obviously wrong.

So my question is, can anyone help to sort out the axis labels in a way that they reflect the underlying dataset and maybe also have six instead of five breaks? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to specify any `library` calls in your code?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It needs library(fmsb)